# ПЕРЕМЕСТИТЬ — PERMUTACION: случайное сходство?

Tags: этимология, приставка, историческая-грамматика, латиница-кириллица, историческое-словообразование

В русском языке есть приставочные ПЕРЕМЕСТИТЬ, ПЕРЕМЕЩАТЬ.

А в латинском есть PERMUTATIO — перемена, изменение; PER-MUTO, PERMUTO — совершенно изменять, менять, обменивать; PER-ΜITΤΟ — метать, пускать, бросать.

В английском, немецком и французском есть PERMUTATION — перестановка, перемещение.
А в испанском это PERMUTACION — перестановка.

Похоже, что везде присутствует приставка PER.
Но каким образом латинская PER- могла стать современной русской ПЕР-?

Известен ли лингвистике такой исторический переход?

Comment: Где-то я слышал, что это не редкое явление. Только объяснений ему пока никто не дал.

Скажем, ведь русское (ПЕРЕ)МЕСТИТЬ - имеет совсем иную основу - МЕСТО. А в латинском PERMUTO и  PER-ΜITΤΟ? Здесь, кажется, у каждого слова свой корень: MUTO (мутация, изменение) и MITTO (напоминающее русск. МЕТАТЬ).

Comment: Не нужно забывать, что у индо-европейских языков есть общее происхождение. Но muto - это изменять , и пермутация - это изменение, заменя, тогда как место по-латински loco